# Is a struct full of function pointers a good solution for C++ binary compatibility?

Tags: c++, dll, binary-compatibility

I have a library written in C++ that I need to turn into a DLL. This library should be able to be modified and recompiled with different compilers and still work.

I have read that it's very unlikely that I will achieve full binary compatibility between compilers/version if I export all my classes directly using __declspec(dllexport).

I have also read that pure virtual interfaces can be pulled from the DLL to remove the issue of name mangling by simply passing a table full of function pointers. However, I have read that even this can fail, because some compilers may even change the order of the functions in the vtable between successive releases.

So finally, I figured I could just implement my own vtable, and this is where I am at:

**Test.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class TestItf;
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) TestItf* __cdecl CreateTest();

class TestItf {
public:
    static TestItf* Create() {
        return CreateTest();
    }
    void Destroy() {
        (this->*vptr->Destroy)();
    }
    void Print(const char *something) {
        (this->*vptr->Print)(something);
    }
    ~TestItf() {
        cout << "TestItf dtor" << endl;
    }
    typedef void(TestItf::*pfnDestroy)();
    typedef void(TestItf::*pfnPrint)(const char *something);

    struct vtable {
        pfnDestroy Destroy;
        pfnPrint Print;
    };    
protected:
    const vtable *const vptr;
    TestItf(vtable *vptr) : vptr(vptr){}
};

extern "C"__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl GetTestVTable(TestItf::vtable *vtable);
```

Test.cpp

```
#include "Test.h"

class TestImp : public TestItf {
public:
    static TestItf::vtable TestImp_vptr;
    TestImp() : TestItf(&TestImp_vptr) {

    }
    ~TestImp() {
        cout << "TestImp dtor" << endl;
    }
    void Destroy() {
        delete this;
    }
    void Print(const char *something) {
        cout << something << endl;
    }
};

TestItf::vtable TestImp::TestImp_vptr =  {
    (TestItf::pfnDestroy)&TestImp::Destroy,
    (TestItf::pfnPrint)&TestImp::Print,
};

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl GetTestVTable(TestItf::vtable *vtable) {
        memcpy(vtable, &TestImp::TestImp_vptr, sizeof(TestItf::vtable));
    }
    __declspec(dllexport) TestItf* __cdecl CreateTest() {
        return new TestImp;
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    TestItf *itf = TestItf::Create();
    itf->Print("Hello World!");
    itf->Destroy();

    return 0;
}
```

Were my above assumptions correct about not being able to achieve proper compatibility with the first two methods?

Is my 3rd solution portable and safe?

-Specifically, I am worried about the effect of using the casted function pointers from TestImp on the base type TestItf. It does seem to work in this simple test case, but I imagine things like alignment or varying object layout might make this unsafe in some cases.

**Edit**
This method can also be used with C#. A few minor modifications have been made to the above code.

Test.cs

```
struct TestItf {
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct VTable {
        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
        public delegate void pfnDestroy(IntPtr itf);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.ThisCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public delegate void pfnPrint(IntPtr itf, string something);

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
        public pfnDestroy Destroy;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
        public pfnPrint Print;
    }

    [DllImport("cppInteropTest", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern void GetTestVTable(out VTable vtable);

    [DllImport("cppInteropTest", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern IntPtr CreateTest();

    private static VTable vptr;
    static TestItf() {
        vptr = new VTable();
        GetTestVTable(out vptr);
    }

    private IntPtr itf;
    private TestItf(IntPtr itf) {
        this.itf = itf;
    }

    public static TestItf Create() {
        return new TestItf( CreateTest() );
    }

    public void Destroy() {
        vptr.Destroy(itf);
        itf = IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    public void Print(string something) {
        vptr.Print(itf, something);
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        TestItf test = TestItf.Create();
        test.Print("Hello World!");
        test.Destroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are going to go that far, just offer a C interface which will be binary compatible almost by definition...

Comment: I am inclined to listen to you on account of this potentially being one extremely painful "I told you so"... but I am 99% sure this will work. Android's OpenSLES API uses this method with the exception that they pass "self" as the first parameter when calling the fptrs in the struct, rather than calling them on the base ptr with __thiscall calling convention. As far as I know, __thiscall is the same as __stdcall, with the exception that "this" is moved into ecx. So as long as (&TestItf == &TestImp) I don't see how this can fail. Is your comment based on code style? or technical concerns?

Comment: Another alternative is to expose that table of function pointers as a COM class. Doesn't necessarily mean you're going to follow all the COM rules, just that you standardize on the COM _layout_. Limited to Windows, of course, but you said "DLL".

Comment: @AlBundy: Providing a C api means that you are playing in *familiar* territory, you can read on how that should or should not be done, there is *experience*. At the same time you allow non-C++ code to interact with your library, which is probably a good thing, and restricting yourself to a C api makes it more obvious to you and others what can and cannot be used there. Will this approach work? I am not that familiar with Windows calling conventions to answer that. Providing a C interface will work (with diligent care)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Interoperability between languages in a convenient object-oriented way was a big part of my original motivation for exploring this idea.

While the C# example used in the original question does work under windows, it fails on mac osx. The sizes of the vtables between C#/Mono and C++ do not match up due to different sizes of member function pointers. Mono expects a 4 byte function pointer, while the xcode/c++ compiler expects them to be 8 bytes.

Apparently, member function pointers are more than just pointers. Sometimes, they can point to structures that contain extra data to deal with certain inheritance situations.

Truncating the 8 byte member function pointers to 4 bytes and sending them to mono anyways actually works. This is probably because I am using a POD class type. I wouldn't want to rely on a hack like this though.

All things considered, the method used for interop suggested in the original question will be much more trouble than it's worth, and I've chosen to byte the bullet, and go with a C interface.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: your TestItf destructor should be virtual because you return a descendant type as a base ancestor. Without virtuality, there will be a memory leak on some compilers.

Now according to binary compatibility. There are following generic pitfalls:

1. Calling conventions. If both compilers (your and client one) are aware about the calling convention you chosen, it's OK (since then, plain classless stdcall convention like Win32 API does is a proven solution for years and multiple languages, not only C++)
2. Structures alignment. Pack your published structures with 1-byte alignment - most of compilers has appropriate setting via pragma or compilation keys.

Keeping that two points in mind you'll play safe in mostly any platform.

Comment: I had to check this, but both destructors do get called. "delete" is delegated back into the DLL by the explicit Destroy function, where it knows its a TestImp, and calls both destructors. The destructor does not have to be, and should not be virtual, because TestItf is supposed to mimic a pure virtual interface which will never have data members, and because making TestItf a virtual class would make it a non-POD class with a potentially compiler specific layout.

Comment: About alignment: now that I think about it, the base class is not actually empty, but contains one pointer, So I wonder if the derived class could ever end up with an alignment greater than the size of a pointer in practice.

Comment: About the destructor, make them `protected` so that users are *forced* to call the `Destroy` function. You are limiting your types to only *heap*, but you were already doing that implicitly above. @Al: *not be virtual, because TestItf is supposed to mimic a pure virtual interface which will never have data members* completely unrelated. You don't make a destructor virtual because this type has/hasn't data member, but because you want polymorphic destructors and your derived type *can* have something to do on destruction. Agree on avoiding `virtual` to remain a POD though, that is a good reason

Comment: @Al: Same thing for constructors, your type **must** be confined to dynamically allocated objects (since you the mechanism for destruction will only work through the `Destroy` function). You don't want users `copying` the object and ending up with a half sliced version where the object is `TestItf` and the `vptr` refers to `TestImp`, as that will most surely cause undefined behavior